# xamarin listview get selected item

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Cannot figure out a proper way get an item from ListView.

My XAML bindings:

```
            <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemTapped="MyListView_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout>

                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Email}"></Label>
                            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" WidthRequest="20" HeightRequest="20"></Image>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

All the data gets displayed and works fine. Class is called Forums:

```
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public List<Result> Results { get; set; }

    public class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("photoUrl")]
        public string PhotoUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

I have made MyListView_ItemTapped Function and for now, I'm trying to display its name when the item is tapped on, but not sure what is a proper way to do it. And I always think that I'm just **bodging** some random things together until I get something.

```
        private void MyListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        var index = forums.Results.IndexOf(e.Item as Forums.Result);
        DisplayAlert("Alert", forums.Results[index].Name, "OK");

    }
```

So if anyone could point me to the better direction or even give few better examples or just explain how should it be done.

Comment: Why go in and out of `e.Results` just use `e.Item.Name`, `e.Item as Forums.Result` anyway

Comment: cannot do that. e.item only has (getHash, equals, getType, tostring())

Comment: you need to cast it to `Forums.Result`, `e.item` is the item tapped which ought to be a `Result`

Answer (score 2):

just cast e.Item to the correct type

```
var item = e.Item as Forums.Result;

// then use item.Name, etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use selected item property 
`<ListView  **SelectedItem="{Binding Result, Mode=TwoWay}">**`

code behind:

`private Result _result;

```
public Result Result
{
    get { return _deviceSession; }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _deviceSession, value);
    }
}`
```

From this class object you can able to get all data

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to the correct Class

```
private void MyListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        var index = forums.Results.IndexOf(e.Item as Forums.Result);
        var selectedItem = (Forums.Result)e.Item;
        if(selectedItem != null)
        {
           DisplayAlert("Alert", selected|Item.Name, "OK");
        }

    }
```

Oh and if you want to remove the selecteditem effect just

```
if (sender is ListView lv) lv.SelectedItem = null;
```