# Retrieving an Item from a list view in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have a list view where I display a bunch of aircrafts. On my Listview I declared an ItemTapped event where I am just trying to collect the damn ID from the listview. I got everything here on the same page just so I can figure it out.

```
 private async void AircraftListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {

        var selected= e.Item as SelectedAircraft;

        var newId = selected.ID;
        //This returns a null 
        int d = 2;


        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new AddPreviousExperience(Id.ToString()));
    }

    public class SelectedAircraft
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string AircraftType { get; set; }

        public string AircraftName { get; set; }
        public string noOfEngines { get; set; }
        public string engineType { get; set; }
        public string AircraftMass { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Have you checked in debug mode that ItemTappedEventArgs e is populated?

Comment: Yes, it brings through the correct item, also mapped correctly from what I can see, if I look on my e and I navigate to Groups, I find the correct item and information there,

Comment: (Under e.Item too)

Comment: Hmm then I am afraid I cannot help you further, maybe you can check your code with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54281705/xamarin-listview-get-selected-item In this question someone has it working maybe you forgot a step?

Comment: It's crazy, the second I cast it to the class it gets null. I am going to have a look there and see if I can get it

Comment: if the cast returns null, the cast is failing.  What is the type of `ItemSource`?  Is it a `List<SelectedAircraft>`?

Comment: It is an observable collection of Selected Aircrafts

Comment: I had done a demo on my device and I can get the id from the selected item correctly. So can you show more detail about you code or post your project to the github? And I can test it on my device.

Comment: you need to step through each line in the debugger and determine exactly which line is not working as expected.  Based on what you've told us this should work.  If you can post the code somewhere I will take a quick look at it